# Golang Gin: Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200

Tags: go, http, web-applications, http-headers, http-redirect

I'm developing a control panel and had hired some people to build it for me. They all bailed and I'm left having to cleanup the spaghetti.

What I need to do is this:

- Pull up Login page
- Check login info and post form
- After post is successful, redirect to dashboard page

Just a simple login process. Problem is that when the login succeeds, the console enters into this redirect loop as you can see below:

```
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:32 | 301 |  1.224601041s |             ::1 | POST     "/login"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:33 | 200 |    787.3905ms |             ::1 | GET      "/dashboard"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:33 | 200 |  197.989875ms |             ::1 | GET      "/login"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:34 | 200 |  817.293166ms |             ::1 | GET      "/dashboard"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:34 | 200 |  206.107791ms |             ::1 | GET      "/login"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:35 | 200 |  792.954375ms |             ::1 | GET      "/dashboard"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:35 | 200 |  201.972708ms |             ::1 | GET      "/login"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:36 | 200 |  840.773625ms |             ::1 | GET      "/dashboard"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:36 | 200 |  198.680125ms |             ::1 | GET      "/login"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:37 | 200 |  897.679708ms |             ::1 | GET      "/dashboard"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:37 | 200 |  200.759917ms |             ::1 | GET      "/login"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:38 | 200 |   795.39975ms |             ::1 | GET      "/dashboard"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:38 | 200 |     196.538ms |             ::1 | GET      "/login"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:39 | 200 |  844.680709ms |             ::1 | GET      "/dashboard"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:39 | 200 |  180.598084ms |             ::1 | GET      "/login"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:40 | 200 |  814.666208ms |             ::1 | GET      "/dashboard"
[GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code 301 with 200
[GIN] 2023/02/21 - 15:43:40 | 200 |     210.281ms |             ::1 | GET      "/login"
```

Now, since I'm picking up the slack of old devs, I'm still studying/new to Golang and Gin so bare with me...

From what I understand, `main()` is configuring the routes, middleware, loading templates then running the engine.

**main.go**

```
func main() {
    //gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode) // uncomment for production

    // Startup Tasks
    startup()
    logging.LogInfo("Ran Startup Tasks...")

    // Configure Engine
    hostPort := fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s:%d",
        dataManagers.LoadConfig().Bshost,
        dataManagers.LoadConfig().Bsport)
    webEngine := gin.Default()
    webEngine.SetTrustedProxies([]string{hostPort})
    logging.LogInfo("Configured Engine...")

    // Load Middleware
    store := cookie.NewStore([]byte(randstr.String(64)))
    webEngine.Use(sessions.Sessions("session", store))
    webEngine.Use(errorHandler.ErrorsHandler500())
    logging.LogInfo("Loaded Middleware...")

    // Configure Routes
    pubRoutes := webEngine.Group("/")
    privRoutes := webEngine.Group("/")
    routes.PublicRoutes(pubRoutes)
    privRoutes.Use(middleware.AuthRequired)
    routes.PrivateRoutes(privRoutes)
    logging.LogInfo("Configured Routes...")

    // Non Routables
    webEngine.NoRoute(errorHandler.ErrorsHandler404())
    logging.LogInfo("Configured Non-Routables...")

    // Load Template Files
    LoadTemplates(webEngine)
    logging.LogInfo("Loaded Templates...")

    // Start the Gin Engine
    err := webEngine.Run(hostPort)
    logging.LogInfo("...BlockSuite-WebUI Loaded")
    logging.Catch(err)
}
```

When `/` is accessed, I'm redirected to `/login` which brings up the login form.

I submit the form with valid credentials and it redirects me to `/dashboard`. I don't know if redirect is the correct thing to do after a successful sign-in, that is what the original dev did and it worked fine.

**routes.go**

```
func PublicRoutes(webEngine *gin.RouterGroup) {
    webEngine.GET("/login", entry.LoginGetHandler)
    webEngine.POST("/login", entry.LoginPostHandler)
    webEngine.GET("/", other.IndexGetHandler())
}
func PrivateRoutes(webEngine *gin.RouterGroup) {
    dashboardRoutes := webEngine.Group("/dashboard")
    {
        dashboardRoutes.GET("/", dashboard.DashboardGetHandler)
    }
}
```

**login.go**

```
func LoginGetHandler(context *gin.Context) {
    user := utility.GetUserSession(context).Get("userEmail")
    if user != nil {
        context.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/dashboard")
    }
    context.HTML(http.StatusOK, "login.html", gin.H{
        "siteKey":    dataManagers.GetRecaptchaSettings().SiteKey,
        "enabled":    dataManagers.GetRecaptchaSettings().Enabled,
        "content":    "",
        "success":    "",
        "serverLogo": brand.GetBrandLogo(),
        "title":      "Welcome back",
    })
}
func LoginPostHandler(context *gin.Context) {
    user := utility.GetUserSession(context).Get("userEmail")
    if user != nil {
        context.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/dashboard")
        //return
    }
    userEmail := utility.Sanitize(context.PostForm("email"))
    password := utility.Sanitize(context.PostForm("password"))
    rememberme := utility.Sanitize(context.PostForm("rememberme"))
    //captcha := context.PostForm("g-recaptcha-response")
    if !utility.IsEmailValid(userEmail) {
        context.HTML(http.StatusBadRequest, "login.html", gin.H{"content": "Please enter a valid email address"})
        return
    }
    /*if helpers2.RecaptchaCheck(captcha) || dataManagers.GetConfig().SiteKey != "" {
        // success
    } else {
        if dataManagers.GetConfig().Enabled {
            context.HTML(http.StatusBadRequest, "login.html", gin.H{"content": "Please verify captcha"})
            return
        }
    }*/
    if utility.EmptyUserPass(userEmail, password) {
        context.HTML(http.StatusBadRequest, "login.html", gin.H{"content": "Email and password cannot be empty"})
        return
    }

    if utility.CheckForWhiteSpaces(userEmail, password) != nil {
        context.HTML(http.StatusBadRequest, "login.html", gin.H{"content": "Username and password can't contain spaces"})
        return
    }
    if !utility.CheckUserPass(userEmail, password) {
        context.HTML(http.StatusUnauthorized, "login.html", gin.H{"content": "Incorrect username or password"})
        return
    }
    utility.NewUserSession(context, userEmail)
    if rememberme == "yes" {
        utility.SetSessionAge(context)
    }
    context.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/dashboard")
}
```

And then, the `/dashboard` page is supposed to be loaded.

**dashboard.go**

```
func DashboardGetHandler(context *gin.Context) {
    user := utility.GetUserSession(context).Get("userEmail")
    db := dataManagers.GetDB()
    if user == nil {
        context.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/login")
    }
    [...]
    context.HTML(http.StatusOK, "dashboard.html", gin.H{
        "info":       info,
        "imageUrl":   utility.GetImage(user),
        "serverLogo": brand.GetBrandIcon(),
        "title":      "Dashboard",
        "serverName": dataManagers.GetServerInfo().Servername,
    })
}
```

(In the `dashboard.go` code, I omitted the code that pulls data into the dashboard as it is long and don't think it is that necessary.)

- I have commented out all of the data queries from the dashboard.go and added a simple "hi" response and it still did a redirect look. So, I know there is nothing wrong with the way this gofile is pulling data.
- I tried using different HTTP response codes like `http.StatusOK` and no dice.
- I verified in dashboard.go that session data is indeed being written and saved. When loading the dashboard GET handler func, I was able to output session data. So, I know for a fact the session is operating fine.
- I changed how the handlers were written. Previously, it was coded as follows:

---

```
func DashboardGetHandler() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(context *gin.Context) {
    [...]
    }
}
```

I'm completely out of ideas and don't know where to go from here. Thanks!

Comment: You can’t override a response that has already been sent to the client.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I'm not too sure on what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: @JimB I understand that is what the console is telling me, I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Your question states you wanted to “override the status code”, which is not possible in the http protocol. How do you want it fixed? Perhaps CeriseLimón’s suggestion of returning early?

Comment: @JimB no no no, the title of the question is what the error message is... It's in the first code block I added. I tried what Cerise mentioned and it still did a loop.

Comment: @xR34P3Rx Fix the errors reported in the log by inserting a return statement after the calls to context.Redirect. What is the loop that you refer to?

Comment: @CeriseLimón I did that, and it still did not work. Well as I explained in the question, after POST and context.Redirect. `/dashboard` kicks me back to `/login` for some reason... then `/login` see's that there is an active session and kicks me back to `/dashboard` and it never stops...

Comment: To debug redirect, confirm that utility.GetUserSession finds the session created by utility.NewUserSession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone that pitched in to help. I got with the previous dev and he helped me figure out what was wrong.

In his code, he had created a middleware func that, for some reason, checked the session again. That piece of code was checking old vars that did not exist in the session cookies. Because of that, I was getting kicked back to the login screen.

So, all I did was remove that middleware since I was handling that in login.go anyways.